# Down sampling and Moving Average in R

Tags: r, time-series, rstudio, downsampling

I have a very large signal with 20Hz sampling frequency and I am using moving average (movavg) fuction with n=20 to make it smooth but in result I get a signal with the same sampling rate as the input. Is there a function which takes input and applies moving average filter and return a down sampled signal. 
Best Regards.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please see [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]  and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example] on how to create a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep one observation every 20 of the smoothed signal `x[x%%20 == 0]`.

Which one you take must not have a significant impact as long as it is regular. You can get reassurance by comparing `x[x%%20==0]`, `x[x%%20==1]`, `x[x%%20==2]`,...